# Java Native Interface - Using a third party dll file in java

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface, native

Edited Question:

Trying to use a .dll file from Java using JNA. I've managed to:

Add the .dll to the System Library - System.loadLibrary("NativeLibrary");

Created a a NativeInterface to map the functions in the .dll/.h file:

```
public interface NativeInterface extends Library, StdCallLibrary {
        public int methodA(packageURL.NativeInterface.typeDefName n);
        public int methodB();

        public static class typeDefName implements Structure.ByReference{

            public typeDefName(short s) {}  
    }
}
```

Added the mapping to my function name because its name in the .dll is "mangled" - Found this out using Dependency Walker

```
        Map options = new HashMap();
    options.
        put(
            Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, 
            new Mapper() {
                public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, Method method) {
                    return super.getFunctionName(library, method);
                }
            }
        );
```

AND:

```
class Mapper implements FunctionMapper{
    public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, Method method) {
       return "?" + method.getName() + "@@YAHPAEIPAPAXFPAUtypeDefName@@@Z";
    }

}
```

Now (What I'm not sure of) Is how to create an Object of typeDefName to pass into Method A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to use an existing DLL from Java, you can use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)
 without doing any native programming at all. JNA accesses the methods of third-party shared libraries dynamically. You could use the library directly or use JNA to write a convenient wrapper entirely in Java.

When you click the link, be sure to scroll down -- there's lots of documentation and stuff, but the top of the page is consumed by a file listing so it doesn't look very useful until you scroll down.

Comment: Getting closer using this, I'm now getting:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function methodA

Using Dependency Walker the function name is being changed to:
?methodA@@YAHPAEIPAPAXFPAU@@@Z

Looking around it looks like I need to map this/change the function name when it sees methodA to ?methodA@@YAHPAEIPAPAXFPAU@@@Z. Any advice?

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, JNA doesn't really handle C++ mangled names. DLLs intended for third-party cross-language reuse generally don't include them, but sadly yours apparently does. You could look at BridJ (http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) which is not nearly so mature, but tries to support C++ better than JNA. Another alternative, actually, would be to generate Java wrappers using SWIG (http://www.swig.org/). SWIG is a great product, but then you do need to compile the generated native code and link it into libraries, so it's not as easy to use as JNA -- but you don't have to write any C++ code yourself.

Comment: Got further by creating a FunctionMapper, Just changed the getMethodName to what the function is actually called in the .dll.

It doesn't like one of the paramets I'm passing to the function though. Its defined in the .h files typedef...

Comment: Managed to Map everything to the method I need. Just need to play around with the values and I'll have it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a book on JNI [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), also containing some code examples.

But I would recommend learning to program in C or C++ first, especially the pointer stuff (as you will need it).

The way you create a DLL file depends on the compiler you use, it is described for some in the aforementioned book...